# Send few response through one http.ResponseWriter

Tags: http, go, http-redirect

after I click on post button on frontend I receive data to my handler, create email and send it, but I want to inform user about status of email(sended or not) and redirect it back to main page. Problem is that I dont know how to pass `alert` and `redirecting to main page` at once.

Here is a handler code:

```
func contactHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
        r.ParseForm()
        /* creating email */
        err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587", smtp.PlainAuth("", *emailFromLogin, *emailFromPassword, "smtp.gmail.com"), *emailFrom, []string{*emailTo}, []byte(msg))
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    }
}
```

That what I want send to user before redirecting.

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<script>Email didn't send<script>")
} else {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<script>Email sent successfully<script>")
}
```

Comment: You can't do it without involving a piece of javascript code on the client side.

Comment: @Зелёный how It should look, like about what I need to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send data back with a redirect request, so here are 2 proposed alternatives.

### Client side navigation

One option would be to send back a normal response with the message you want to show to the user, optionally with the URL to move to. After this, the client may do the navigation.

This may be an AJAX request, and client side JavaScript can process the result, and act upon it: display the message, and navigate. Here are some ways for client side JavaScript navigation:

```
window.location = "http://new-website.com";
window.location.href = "http://new-website.com";
window.location.assign("http://new-website.com");
window.location.replace("http://new-website.com");
```

### Encode message in URL as parameter

Another common way is to send a redirect, and encode the message in the new URL as a query parameter, such as:

```
newPath := "/?msg=Hello"
```

This is a simple example, but if the message is more complex, you have to escape it to get a valid path. For that, you may use [`url.QueryEscape()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape) like this:

```
msg := "Email didn't send"
path := "/?msg=" + url.QueryEscape(msg)
```

This would result in a path `/?msg=Email+didn%27t+send` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qu0CV3LA3E1)). Another option would be to use [`url.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) and [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) to assemble the URL, for example:

```
values := url.Values{}
values.Add("msg", "Email didn't send")

url := &url.URL{
    Path:     "/",
    RawQuery: values.Encode(),
}

fmt.Println(url)
```

The above prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gc0eIwYMD6L)):

```
/?msg=Email+didn%27t+send
```

Of course, the new page must handle that query parameter, e.g. use JavaScript to detect if in this case the `msg` query param exists, and if so, display it somehow to the user.

Also note that you shouldn't use the `StatusMovedPermanently` code for this redirect, as that may be cached by browsers and proxies. Instead use `StatusFound`. This status code indicates to clients that the redirection is temporary and may change in the future, so if the client needs the original URL again, it will query the original again (and not the new one automatically).

Comment: Thanks for so detailed answer